# JQuery UI Tabs - No line border below tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't figure out why any tab selection after the first tab of my JQuery UI set, no line appears underneath.

Pics:

[image: http://i54.tinypic.com/adhzsk.jpg]

[image]

```
<div id="tabs" style="width:750px;margin: 0 auto;">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" onClick="$('#newJudgeLink').hide(); $('#newUserLink').hide();">New Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" onClick="$('#newJudgeLink').hide(); $('#newUserLink').hide();">Old Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3" onClick="$('#newJudgeLink').show(); $('#newUserLink').hide();">Judges</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4" onClick="$('#newJudgeLink').hide(); $('#newUserLink').show();">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5" onClick="$('#newJudgeLink').hide(); $('#newUserLink').hide();">Other Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
```

And then each div has

```
 <div id="tabs-1"> <!-- stuff --> </div>
 <div id="tabs-2"> <!-- stuff --> </div>
```

, etc. And I've double checked and made sure all of the divs are closed. I have no other styling aside from the out-of-the-box JQuery CSS.

Tabs delaration:

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: With a tool like firebug you can check how the CSS of the tabs changed. A little more information about that makes answering the question easier.

Comment: As per Daff's comment, it's going to be CSS at the end of the day. Either something in your CSS is overriding the jQuery UI tab styling, or some piece of Javascript is doing the same. Once the document is rendered, you'll be able to see the inheritance model in Firebug (or similar) as well as any inline styles (likely applied by JS)

Comment: I've just come to realize they only don't show up in IE, if that means anything. Unfortunately the users of this site will be primarily using IE.

Comment: I'll try using Firebug, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I put this line in the top of the document and it works fine.
I only had this problem in IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the **Jquery UI styles** in the original style doesn't contain border.

Add this in to your style sheet:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li { 
    list-style: none; 
    float: left; 
    position: relative; 
    top: 1px; 
    margin: 0 .2em -1px 0; 
    border-bottom: 1px !important; 
    padding: 0; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

In `.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li margin` you need to change original `1px` into `-1px` and `border-bottom: 0px` into `border-bottom: 1px;`